# How can i get currently logged on users in WSS v3 or a count

Tags: sharepoint

How can i get currently logged on users in Sharepoint v3(2007) or a count?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this blog post for a detailed explanation of a possible solution for this problem: http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site